# Set initial chart type for PowerBiQuickCreateDemo

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to work on this basic project for Power BI.

[PowerBiQuickCreateDemo](https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/PowerBiQuickCreateDemo)

In this project if we checkout the file
https://github.com/PowerBiDevCamp/PowerBiQuickCreateDemo/blob/main/App/services/QuickCreateSDK.ts

On line **53** we can see IQuickCreateConfiguration used to create report configuration. I searched on web but couldn't find any example where I can set initial visual chart type of the report. Default state is column chart and I want to make it pie, line chart, etc.

Just want to know whether it is even possible or not.

**NOTE**: I don't want to do configuration in powerbi.

Thanks.

I tried to play around with different configuration available but couldn't find anything.